# Office365: Identify users who are on Litigation hold or In-place hold

Tags: office-365, microsoft-graph

I'm looking for an API call or an attribute in the response for users call via the [Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations), indicating that a user is placed on Litigation hold.
Is this possible? any other REST API endpoint that might serve this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

This is sadly not possible today.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/32111197-graph-api-extensions-to-place-users-on-hold

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46884765/enable-litigation-hold